# can't delete a file after no space left on device

Tags: python, ioerror

I'm writing a bunch of files on several hard disks. All my files don't fit on a single hard drive so I write those on next one if the first one is out of space. I catch the IOError 28 to figure this out.

My exact problem is that when I try to remove the last file written (incomplete file) to the first disk I get a new Exception that I don't fully understand. It seems that with-block can't close the file because there is no space left on a disk.

I'm on windows and disks are formatted to NTFS.

Could someone please help me.

```
# Here's a sample code
# I recommend first to fill a disk to almost full with a large dummy file.
# On windows you could create a dummy file with
#   'fsutil file createnew large.txt 1000067000000'

import os
import errno

fill = 'J:/fill.txt'
try:
    with open(fill, 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            n = f.write(b"\0")
except IOError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.ENOSPC:
        os.remove(fill)
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nospacelef.py", line 8, in <module>
    n = f.write(b"\0")
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nospacelef.py", line 8, in <module>
    n = f.write(b"\0")
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nospacelef.py", line 11, in <module>
    os.remove(fill)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'J:/fill.txt'
```

Comment: I think this error `WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` is quite clear and specifies the reason.

Comment: Doesn't that error (32) happen because the above code doesn't close the file before trying to delete it?

Comment: @ρss It's not that clear to me. How can the file be used by another process since it was open for writing (on Windows)? If this "another process" is actually this same process, then the question is why the `with` statement failed to close the file correctly. File object's context manager guarantees that the file will be closed, and OS-level resources released, even if an exception occurs.

Comment: @nekomatic If the code is run as presented here, the `with` statement should make sure that the file is closed before deleting it.

Comment: OK, I overlooked that. @LauriK what happens if you try to write in chunks of 1K or 10K bytes at a time?

Comment: @user4815162342, that's exactly the problem. with-statement isn't able to close the file. It seems that when it tries another IOError: [Errno 28] is raised. I tried same logic with traditional f = open(fill, 'wb') and then closed the f before remove in except-block then f.close() raises the same IOError.

Comment: Is the `J` a network drive or a local drive? Try to investigate what process is working with your file  & if it is the same process or different one. https://superuser.com/questions/845971/how-do-i-find-out-what-files-a-process-is-writing-to

Comment: @nekomatic, actually I write 1k blocks in my real program but still disks fill up to a state when there is 0 bits left and files can't be deleted.

Comment: @pss, J:\ is a usb hard drive.

Comment: @LauriK This is possible - the `IOError` 28 looks like a result of an attempt of `close()` to flush the write buffer. But failing to flush should not prevent Python from freeing the underlying file handle and releasing the file. If that is indeed what is happening here, it is a bug in Python, or in (Python's use of) Visual Studio's C runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to my own question.

I filed a bug to python [1][2]. It was already fixed in 3.3+. There is no fix for 3.2 that I used. I upgraded my python version so I'm not suffering this problem anymore.

[1] http://bugs.python.org/issue25202

[2] http://bugs.python.org/issue16597